# Add slider to matplotlib chart

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a matplotlib code that generates a simple 2D chart. I want to add sliders widget to it for hte and hre variables (which are arrays) so that hte and hre values can be increased or decreased interactively. Is there a way (I am sure there is because I have seen [something](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/widgets/slider_demo.html) like this on matplotlib website but I am not able to integrate it with my code)? Any help will be appreciated. Here is the code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FixedLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from pylab import *

hte=np.array([10,11,12,13,15,20,21,22,25,30])
hre=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])

k=20*hte
n4=10*hre
t=6
w4=25

x=arange(1,100,10)
d=(log(x)/log(10))/10
y= k + n4 * (d) + t + w4 + 8

matplotlib.pyplot.jet()
lines=plot(x,y)
setp(lines, linewidth=2, color='r')
xlabel('X - Title')
ylabel('Y - title')
title('$Our Chart$')
grid(True)
show()
```

[image: here is the chart that it generates]

Comment: How would you change the values in the array with the slider value. Could you show an example ?

Comment: like, for instance, both sliders would simply slide over their respective discrete array values. Or even, I can declare a formula for hte and hre .. no big deal, but just to show you guys, i mentioned it as an array which is ideal.

Comment: @joaquin could you please help me with a similar problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43381449/how-to-make-two-sliders-in-matplotlib

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following your comment, I selected sliders in a way they multiply the values in the arrays. You should apply your particular algorithm.

```
from pylab import *
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
import numpy as np

hte = np.array([10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 20, 21, 22, 25, 30])
hre = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])

k = 20 * hte
n4 = 10 * hre
t, w4 = 6, 25
x = arange(1, 100, 10)
d = log10(x) / 10

y = k + n4 * d + t + w4 + 8

ax = subplot(111)
subplots_adjust(left=0.15, bottom=0.25)
line, = plot(x, y, linewidth=2, color='r')

xlabel('X - Title')
ylabel('Y - title')
title('$Our Chart$')
grid(True)

axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
axhte = axes([0.15, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03], axisbg=axcolor)
axhre = axes([0.15, 0.15, 0.65, 0.03], axisbg=axcolor)

shte = Slider(axhte, 'hte', 0.1, 30.0, valinit=1)
shre = Slider(axhre, 'hre', 0.1, 10.0, valinit=1)

def update(val):
    k = 20 * hte * shte.val 
    n4 = 10 * hre * shre.val

    y= k + n4 * d + t + w4 + 8

    line.set_ydata(y)    
    ax.set_ylim(y.min(), y.max())  
    draw()

shte.on_changed(update)
shre.on_changed(update)

show()
```

[image]

Comment: joaquin, bro, two words: YOU RULE! :-) One little thing now...increasing and decreasing the sliders actually is incrementing and decrementing the values of hte and hre?? plus, when in the sliders when you define the limits of 0.1 to 30 and 0.1 to 10, what actually it does? Need a little light on this, please.

Comment: moving the sliders you get different values (indicated at the right of the slider). These values can be read from `shre.val` and `shte.val`. I use these variables to multiply your hte and hre arrays in `update`. I defined the min and max values in the sliders as you indicate(0.1 to 30 and 0.1 to 10). You can select whatever limits you need.

Comment: Thank you again, brother. I will incorporate your logic into my code appropriately and will post it over here..i have some other interesting issues, which i will be posting today. :-) thank you very much, once again. you are a life saver.