# How do I provide slider control to a matplotlib plot of a pandas timeseries

Tags: matplotlib, pandas

I am able to plot a a couple of pandas time series as to slots

Stock= A pandas timeseries of stock data

Signal=A pandas timesries if signals from Stock above has the same range

The following displays it the way I want where the dates between the 2 plots are in sync

```
fig=figure(num=None, figsize=(14, 8), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
ax1=fig.add_subplot(211)
ax1.autoscale(True)
Stock.plot(ax=ax1)
ax2=fig.add_subplot(212, sharex=ax1)
Signal.plot(ax=ax2)
fig.set_tight_layout(True)
```

What I want to do is for the plot to display only 1000 bars of data from the whole Stock time series and then implement a Sider below that will allow the plot to slide across the whole range of Stock display a specific range of 1000 bars.

Can some one show me how to do this? I have seen some of the slider examples but I am not able to translate that to pandas plots or what axes or arguments to pass to the Slider object.

Thx,
Sarvi

Comment: which examples did you find but not understand?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11069944/add-slider-to-matplotlib-chart

Answer (score -1):

I would use java script. For this.   Look at http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-time-series