# How to make two sliders in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, slider, odeint

I would like to make two sliders in matplotlib to manually change N and P values in my predator-prey model:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def lotka(x,t,params):
    N, P = x 
    alpha, beta, gamma, delta = params 
    derivs = [alpha*N - beta*N*P, gamma*N*P - delta*P] 
    return derivs

N=2
P=1
alpha=3
beta=0.5
gamma=0.4
delta=3

params = [alpha, beta, gamma, delta]
x0=[N,P]
maxt = 20
tstep = 0.01

t=np.arange(0,maxt,tstep)
equation=odeint(lotka, x0, t, args=(params,))

plt.plot(t,equation)
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("Population size")
plt.legend(["Prey", "Predator"], loc="upper right")

plt.title('Prey & Predator Static Model')
plt.grid(color="b", alpha=0.5, linestyle="dashed", linewidth=0.5)
```

This is my code which produces a graph for fixed initial values of N and P. However, I'd like to change them to see how the plot changes. And for this, I'd like to use sliders like: http://matplotlib.org/users/screenshots.html#slider-demo but I do not know how to add this into my code...

Could anyone please give me any direction? Many thanks!! xx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the example, hope the comments help you understand what's what:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button, RadioButtons
from scipy.integrate import odeint

# Function to draw
def lotka(x, t, params):
    N, P = x
    alpha, beta, gamma, delta = params 
    derivs = [alpha*N - beta*N*P, gamma*N*P - delta*P] 
    return derivs

# Parameters
Nmin = 1
Nmax = 100
Pmin = 1
Pmax = 100
N0 = 2
P0 = 1
alpha = 3
beta = 0.5
gamma = 0.4
delta = 3

params = [alpha, beta, gamma, delta]
x0=[N0,P0]
maxt = 20
tstep = 0.01

# Initial function values
t = np.arange(0, maxt, tstep)
prey, predator = odeint(lotka, x0, t, args=(params,)).T
# odeint returne a shape (2000, 2) array, with the value for
# each population in [[n_preys, n_predators], ...]
# The .T at the end transponses the array, so now we get each population
# over time in each line of the resultint (2, 2000) array.

# Create a figure and an axis to plot in:
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0.10, 0.3, 0.8, 0.6])
prey_plot = ax.plot(t, prey, label="Prey")[0]
predator_plot = ax.plot(t, predator, label="Predator")[0]

ax.set_xlabel("Time")
ax.set_ylabel("Population size")
ax.legend(loc="upper right")
ax.set_title('Prey & Predator Static Model')
ax.grid(color="b", alpha=0.5, linestyle="dashed", linewidth=0.5)
ax.set_ylim([0, np.max([prey, predator])])

# create a space in the figure to place the two sliders:
axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
axis_N = fig.add_axes([0.10, 0.1, 0.8, 0.03], facecolor=axcolor)
axis_P = fig.add_axes([0.10, 0.15, 0.8, 0.03], facecolor=axcolor)
# the first argument is the rectangle, with values in percentage of the figure
# size: [left, bottom, width, height]

# create each slider on its corresponding place:
slider_N = Slider(axis_N, 'N', Nmin, Nmax, valinit=N0)
slider_P = Slider(axis_P, 'P', Pmin, Pmax, valinit=P0)

def update(val):
    # retrieve the values from the sliders
    x = [slider_N.val, slider_P.val]
    # recalculate the function values
    prey, predator = odeint(lotka, x, t, args=(params,)).T
    # update the value on the graph
    prey_plot.set_ydata(prey)
    predator_plot.set_ydata(predator)
    # redraw the graph
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
    ax.set_ylim([0, np.max([prey, predator])])

# set both sliders to call update when their value is changed:
slider_N.on_changed(update)
slider_P.on_changed(update)

# create the reset button axis (where its drawn)
resetax = plt.axes([0.8, 0.025, 0.1, 0.04])
# and the button itself
button = Button(resetax, 'Reset', color=axcolor, hovercolor='0.975')

def reset(event):
    slider_N.reset()
    slider_P.reset()

button.on_clicked(reset)
```

Notice, however, you should have [shown how you tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to adapt the example to what you had and how it was misbehaving.

Nevertheless, welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Many many thanks, this is my very first time here, will post what I did not and did not work... Could not manipulate the output

Comment: I made a comment with the code I was trying to get my solution from. Sorry I have not posted it in my initial Q; will bare this in my mind from now on. Many thanks!

Comment: My guess would go to not using [`on_changed` ](http://matplotlib.org/api/widgets_api.html#matplotlib.widgets.Slider) to associate the change in the sliders to the call of the function to change the data on the graph. But you already showed effort by showing your research, so don't dwell on it.

Comment: And my previous comment was wrong, I should apologize... Last edit: added `ax.set_ylim([0, np.max([prey, predator])])` so you can always see the function. And leave you a question: shouldn't you round those results to `int` values?

Comment: would you also know how to make direction fields and trajectories in the phase plane for this code? I was using this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43383595/direction-fields-and-trajectories-in-the-phase-plane but unfortunately unsuccessfully...

Answer (score 2):

So, I have tried with this code:

```
from scipy import integrate
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button, RadioButtons

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.25)
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("Population size")
plt.legend(["Prey", "Predator"], loc="upper right")

plt.title('Prey & Predator Static Model')
plt.grid(color="b", alpha=0.5, linestyle="dashed", linewidth=0.5)

l1, l2 = plt.plot(t, equation)

axcolor = 'b'
ax_N = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03], axisbg=axcolor)
ax_P = plt.axes([0.25, 0.15, 0.65, 0.03], axisbg=axcolor)

sN = Slider(ax_N, 'N', 0, 80, valinit=1)
sP = Slider(ax_P, 'P', 0, 80, valinit=1)


def update(val):
    N = N*sN.val
    P = P*sP.val
    x = equation
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
    l1, l2.set_ydata(y)    
    ax.set_ylim(y.min(), y.max())  
    draw()

sN.on_changed(update)
sP.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```

I could not manipulate the sliders. Thank you so much @berna1111

Comment: For future reference, you can edit your original post. The problem is in `l1, l2.set_ydata(y)` - you should set the data for each plot separately. I run into a similar issue, and that's why I separated both plots and used the transpose to retrieve each data (prey and predator) in each line. By the way, Stackoverflow can be [nitpicky](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) sometimes, but it's been thought and it's that way for a reason.